# Overflow visible not working with position absolute as child element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For the following HTML list I want to make only it only vertically scrollable and horizontally it should be visible by default.

Even after giving overflow-x as visible it is treating as scroll

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div class="hover-arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div class="hover-arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div class="hover-arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div>Item 4</div>
        <div class="hover-arrow"></div>
    </div>
</div>


.container {
   width: 100px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x: visible;
   border: 1px solid black;
   height: 200px;
}

.inner-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}

.hover-arrow {
   position: absolute;
   right: -20px;
   bottom: 0;
   border-left: 20px solid grey;
   border-top: 30px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

JS fiddle for the same
https://jsfiddle.net/m148ujcn/

Answer (score 2):

According to [W3Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x):

> The computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’. The computed value of ‘overflow’ is equal to the computed value of ‘overflow-x’ if ‘overflow-y’ is the same; otherwise, it is the pair of computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’.

In short:

> If we set overflow-x or overflow-y to **visible** and something else for
> the others, then **visible** value gets treated as **auto**

Made some changes in your fiddle check this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamarmishra/sj32v6w7/3/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;">Item 1</div>
      <div class="hover-arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;">Item 2</div>
     <div class="hover-arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
     <div style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;">Item 3</div>
      <div class="hover-arrow"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: got the problem but in your solution you marked overflow-x as hidden where as I want it to be visible (div : hover-arrow ) should be visible

Comment: the problem is not in the overflow property but in the hover-arrow css itself. You have used position: absolute and right as -20px. If your motive is to have two div in one row, then you should use float: left on both div and clear: both after it. 
right: -20px is increasing the actual box size of the div. 
This can also work if you make right: 0px.